# Training neural networks with very large feature tensors of very little complexity

Tags: neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

This is something of a meta question, detached from code or libraries.

Let's say we have a large array of very primitive elements, like from an image read directly from our hard drive. The important thing is, that the representation of our input data is very simple (bits, bytes, 8 bit integers, along those lines), but there are lots of data points (instead of having 256 32-bit integers we may have 256x32=8192 bits). Let's assume that we do neither know how (or if) these simple data points correlate (i.e. whether they are shorts, integers, floats,...), so their encoding is unknown.
I would like to train a neural network to interpret and decode these data points, but am struggling to think of a way to represent/format my input data.
Since I don't know anything about the encoding (I do have labels of some sort for the input arrays, for example grayscale images) I'd imagine it difficult and prone to errors to assume structure within my data. It would for example be easy to calculate bytes from the bits and reduce my dimensionality by a factor of 8, but I think that might cause a loss of information from structure. For the same reason it's propably not suitable to split up the data into smaller batches.

I looked into this and found articles like [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/handle-long-sequences-long-short-term-memory-recurrent-neural-networks/), but any of the proposed methods would most likely harm the integrity of my data.

I did some experiments combining bits into bytes but this still leaves very large inputs (because they are only reduced by a factor of 8) and did not yield the results I was hoping for. Another Idea I had was to feed the all of the inputs into a CNN to extract features and to propagate those through a RNN (which had reasonable success) but this doesn't scale too well either and harms the data's integrity as well. Another approach was to do something like U-Net where I detect features with a CNN and then propagate these features along with the original inputs into a RNN, but this leads to an explosion of complexity (> 30.000.000 parameters for a mere ~2500 input bits).

Looking forward to suggestions, and I hope that the problem is explained clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it make dounting at first, as you operate on a "raw" data, it is important to note that this is the case for almost every problem, and it is just our human perceptual bias. "Pixel intensities" that need to be mapped to being a cat is a very complex transformation, same way mapping from bits to a float is. Consequently the first intuition would be "to do nothing, just treat it is any other input".

That being said, having good prior can be helpful so it is worth asking oneself what architecture can be seen as a learnable decoder, that can represent decoding to short, ints, floats and so on. The most naive one would be to have *every possible decoding* applied, and then have an attention/transformer on top of it so that a network can learn how to decode your data. In the simplest case you could also just conactenate decoded values through a linear layer (so that network can learn to ignore parts of it).

Comment: Thanks for your input! So Do you think that I can just interpret the bits as bytes and use those as Inputs? Using the bit-array as is results in far too big Networks to be suitable...

Comment: I ended up reshaping my large (one dimensional) input array to two dimensions and extracted features using convolution layers. I then propagated the results, concatenated with the slightly reduced (by a dense layer) original inputs, to a rnn structure and was indeed able to achieve good results, accepting your answer, was helpful!